# Batch consumer with Blocking Collection

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

I'm using Blocking Collection within a producer consumer pattern.
In order to speed up my program, i have to make the consumer process in batch: process a list of items in the blocking collection(50 item) instead of one at a time.

So i tried using `queue.Take(50)` instead of `queue.GetConsumingEnumerable()` method with no luck. 
Is there a way to do that or should i reconsider using the Blocking Collection?

Answer (score 1):

Writing `queue.Take(50)` is using the LINQ `Take` method (rather than the `BlockingCollection` `Take` method) on the *non* consuming enumerable, so you'll end up getting 50 items but leaving them all in the collection.

If you just want to get 50 items you could use `queue.GetConsumingEnumerable().Take(50)` and then you'd be getting 50 items and ensuring that they're actually removed from the collection as you go.  You'd want to materialize the query (using `ToList` or an equivalent) if you want to ensure that you've gotten all 50 items before you start processing any of them.  (That likely wouldn't speed up your processing, it'd probably slow it down, but it is what you asked for.)

Comment: In case the number of item in the Bloking Collection is less than my batch size and i finished adding elements to it. What will happen? Can i still take these elements?

Comment: @mhd You'll get a partial batch.

Comment: i tried queue.GetConsumingEnumerable().Take(50) however it returns 0 or 1 item not 50

Comment: @mhd Did you complete the collection without adding enough items for that worker to get more than 0 or 1 items?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. The producer is fast and i have to do queue.CompleteAdding() at any time

Answer (score 0):

Starting from .NET 6, you can use the [`Chunk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk) LINQ operator:

```
// Splits the elements of a sequence into chunks of size at most size.
public static IEnumerable<TSource[]> Chunk<TSource> (
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int size);
```

Usage example:

```
foreach (Item[] chunk in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable().Batch(50))
{
    // Process the chunk that contains 50 items, unless it is the last chunk.
}
```